# i try to pass the value from php to py but i does not show anything

Tags: php, python

i am working on the project and i try to pass the variable from php to python to execute the python code but it does not show anything. then i lookup some source in the internet and copy the same exactly but it does not show anything

my test.php

```
<?php
  $data = 'hello';
  $output = shell_exec("python3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/test.py "  . $data);
 ?>
```

my test.py

```
import sys
result = sys.argv[1]

print (result)
```

Comment: what is the result you have here ?

Comment: whats does `python3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/test.py hello` output when you run it on a console? If you run `test.php` on a webserver, make sure the webserver user has permission to read/execute the python script..

Comment: i believe the system will print out hello on the web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving python 3 arguments with shell_exec.
The first one is always python3, the second one in your case is `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/test.py` and the third one is `'hello'`.
The arguments list (`sys.argv`) is as follows (the numbers at the top are the list indexes):

```
     0                               1                                  2
['python3', '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/test.py', 'hello']
```

If you want to store the variable 'hello' you need to select the other index in the list:

```
result = sys.argv[2]
```

Comment: I changed it and it is not printing anything. it only showed white page

Comment: i believe the command shell_exec is executed. it does not return anything